# what is the logic behind this code

Tags: java

I would like to to understand how the output works here from this java code.. 
kindly help !
I took this code from a book called Head First Java
here is the code:

```
public class EchoTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Echo e1 = new Echo();
        Echo e2 = new Echo(); // the correct answer
        //or
        Echo e2 = e1; // is the bonus answer!
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 4) {
            e1.hello();
            e1.count = e1.count + 1;
            if (x == 3) {
                e2.count = e2.count + 1;
            }
            if (x > 0) {
                e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;
            }
            x = x + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(e2.count);
    }
}

class Echo {

    int count = 0;

    void hello() {
        System.out.println("helloooo... ");
    }
}
```

and this is the output:

```
  %java EchoTestDrive
   helloooo...
   helloooo...
   helloooo...
   helloooo...
   10
```

Comment: Which part, specifically, don't you understand?

Comment: Please format your code prior to posting.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : why hello is printed four times & atlast a 10 ?

Comment: Is that even compiling? Two variables with the same.. Specifically `e2`

Comment: @Buba1947 - have a look at the innre if(x>0) where e2 is incremented by e1. You can "play" the code and the variable values on paper and should see why 10 is printed.

Comment: @LewsTherin I think the OP wants to formulate two questions in one code statement, that's what I read within the comments.

Comment: @LewsTherin : I took this code from a book called Head First java

Comment: In its current form, this is not a very clear question.

Comment: @NPE which part is not clear here ?

Comment: @all : my question was to understand this code, i pasted this code as it is from the book which I couldn't understand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well....

`helloooo...` being output 4 times is from...

```
    while (x < 4) {
        e1.hello();
        x = x + 1;
    }
```

As for the count to 10, (assuming   `Echo e2 = e1;` is meant to be  `Echo e3 = e1;`...

After iteration `x = 0`: e1.count == 1, e2.count == 0;

After iteration `x = 1`: e1.count == 2, e2.count == 2;

After iteration `x = 2`: e1.count == 3, e2.count == 5;

After iteration `x = 3`: e1.count == 4, e2.count == 10;

Though that interpretation leaves e3 completely unused.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what this question could be about except aliasing. If you have this line:

```
Echo e2 = new Echo();
```

then `e2` is an object separate from `e1` and has its own `count` variable. If you use this:

```
Echo e2 = e1;
```

then you have a total of one `Echo` instance, pointed to by both `e1` and `e2`.

The rest is just fiddly details on how and when the `count` variable is updated in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The example is like fill in the blanks from source code pool.

You have completed it fine and you might be wondering why the difference occurs for below

```
Bonus Answer! 
24
correct Answer!
10
```

In correct case which is

```
Echo e2 = new Echo(); // the correct answer
```

You are creating separate instance of `Echo` so it will has its own `count` and every time you say `e2.count` you are accessing this count.

In Bonus Answer case

```
Echo e2 = e1;
```

You have two references point to same object so when you do `e2.count` you are accessing `count` for `e1` and `e2`